# Strange phenomenon about MFC class CRect?

Tags: mfc

I have a dialog based program and two range CRect rc1(0,0,1024,768), rc2(0,1,1024,768). I use `MoveWindow` function to move the dialog, the dialog will appear at the center of the screen when using rc1, but the left for rc2?

Why?

Comment: Where do you call MoveWindow ? Which version Visual Studio do you use ? Which is the size of your screen ? Show some code.

Comment: What are is your screen resolution? What is happening when using `rc2`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a "feature" of MFC. A dialog with coordinates 0,0 will automatically be centered by the CDialog::CheckAutoCenter() function that is located in dlgcore.cpp which is one of the source files of MFC. This function is called by MFC **after** OnInitdialog.